# Do something on previous activity when back pressed from current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, onbackpressed

I have  Activity A and B. From activity A, I have opened activity B with Transparent background. So activity A is still visible in the background. Now I want to close activity B on the back button press and start a particular function( or call a method ) on activity A.

Anyone please help me with a solution!

Comment: you're probably looking for `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Except startActivityForResult is deprecated.

Comment: @KristyWelsh i haven't needed to use `startActivityForResult` in a such long time, i'm not sure if it's officially deprecated yet but i saw `registerForActivityResult` is a thing now, [source](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by the new Activity Result APIs that were recently introduced in AndroidX Activity 1.2.0-alpha02 and Fragment 1.3.0-alpha02 and it is recommended to use them for their advantages over startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() APIs. You can read the implementation and advantages here -> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result